# How to convert fixed length fields in a file to space delimited

Tags: awk, perl

I have a fixed length matrix type file where each field is 20 characters long.

1. How can I convert this to a space delimited file?

Also there are some missing values, which I would like to replace with a hyphen (`-`).

2. How could I achieve this?

I will be using the output for `awk` operations.

*Example input with 10 character field length file.*

```
 head1     head2     head3
 a         b         c
           c          
 c                   a
```

*Example output*

```
head1 head2 head3
a b c
- c -
c - c
```

Comment: Each table element is only 1 character long?

Comment: that may not be the case, this is just an example.

Comment: not `awk`, but alternatively, `tr` will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl:

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$width = 10}
    while (length) {
        ($word = substr($_,0,$width)) =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # trim whitespace
        $word ||= "-";
        print $word, " "; 
        substr($_,0,$width) = "";
    }
    print "\n";
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
sed 's/^ //g' input | tr -s "[:blank:]" "," | \
awk -F, '!$1{printf "- "} $1{printf "%s ", $1} \
  !$2{printf "- "} $2{printf "%s ", $2} \
  !$3{print "-"} $3{print $3}'
```

**Explanation:**

- `sed 's/^ //g' input` removes a leading space if present
- `tr -s "[:blank:]" ","`: replaces all spaces with comma
- `awk ...`: uses the delimiter `,` and prints the values or `-` if the value is empty.

Comment: That will break if there are 2 or more whitespace-separated words within the fixed-width field.

Answer (score 1):

Awk way

```
awk '{for(x=0;x<length($0);x+=10)y=y" "((z=substr($0,x,10))~/[[:graph:]]/?z:"-")
      gsub(/ +/," ",y);print y;y=""}' file
```

If they can have spaces in the fields

```
awk '{for(x=0;x<length($0);x+=10){z=gensub(/(^ +| +$)/,"", "g",substr($0,x,10))
      y=y" "(z?z:"-")}print y;y=""}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gawk` then you can use `FIELDWIDTHS` variable which tells `gawk` how to split input with fixed, columnar boundaries. It is an experimental feature. Assigning to `FIELDWIDTHS` overrides the use of `FS` for field splitting.

Here is example of usage,

```
gawk 'BEGIN{
             FIELDWIDTHS = "10 10 10"
           }
           {
             s = q = "" 
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
             { 
               s = $i
               gsub(/ +/,"",s)
               s = (length(s) )? s : "-"
               q = sprintf("%s%s%s",q,(length(q)?OFS:""),s)  
             } 
               print q
           }
      ' file
```

Comment: thanks Akshay, I have thousands of columns to work with and not just 3, can that be adapted?